# выдает ошибку 508

Tags: wordpress

выдает

> Resource Limit Is Reached The website is temporarily unable to service
>   your request as it exceeded resource limit. Please try again later.

плохо разбираюсь в тех части, что мне сделать, подскажите. не возможно работать на этом сайте.

Comment: Хороший пример того, как не надо задавать вопросы, если хотите, чтобы вам помогли. Ваше решение [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Смайлы в вопросах.. Если честно вам сказать, то это вызывает отвращение к чтению подобных вопросов, и дачи ответов к ним. Вы не в соц. сети. на данном ресурсе необходимо не эмоции выражать, а то как сильно быстро вы хотите получить ответ на ваш вопрос, и это необходимо выражать в очень хорошо описанном вопросе.

Comment: ДОБРЫЙ ВЕЧЕР!Я не использовала ни одного смайлика,а попросила помощи! не можете ответить конкретно,не надо  писать что у вас там вызывает отвращение...

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего указывает на то, что ваш сайт потребляет больше чем дает вам хостинг (озу, память, кол-во запросов и т.д.). Возможно чего то из них не хватает и вам нужно это проверить или написать хостингу.
Может поможет узнать плагин https://wordpress.org/plugins/server-ip-memory-usage/ или поищите аналоги.